# Android service bind trouble

Tags: android, exception, service, bind, classcastexception

Hello community I have the following problem.

My manifest file looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.someCo.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />   
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <service android:name = ".BackgroundService" android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my Activity's onCreate has the following line of code.

```
this.context.startService(new Intent(this.context, com.someCo.test.BackgroundService.class));
         this.context.bindService(new Intent(this.context, com.someCo.test.BackgroundService.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

my Activity also has the following private class.

```
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public static final String TAG = "Service Connection Class";

          public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

              try {
                com.someCo.test.BackgroundService.MyBinder binder = (com.someCo.test.BackgroundService.MyBinder)service;
                backgroundService = binder.getService();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //backgroundService = ((BackgroundService.MyBinder) service).getService();

            //Toast.makeText(context,"service connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.i(TAG, "onServiceConnected");


          }


          //@Override
          public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            backgroundService = null;
          }
        };
```

my Service has the following.

```
    private final IBinder binder = new MyBinder();

public class MyBinder extends Binder{

    private static final String TAG = "MyBinder";


    BackgroundService getService(){
        Log.i(TAG, "get service");
        return BackgroundService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "onBind destroyed");
    return binder;

}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onUnbind destroyed");
  return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

At this line I get the exception below the code.

```
(com.someCo.test.BackgroundService.MyBinder)service;
                    backgroundService = binder.getService();
```

java.lang.classCastException: android.os.BinderProxy.

Could someone kindly point me to my mistake, I can't seem to figure it out. Please forgive the very verbose code, as I was trying to be as explicit as possible in debugging this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have written the code for start Service using both way(StartService and BindService)?

Here is the [example for the Bind Service](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/05/bind-service-using-ibinder-class.html). you can refer this blog.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this thing my self several times. But from my experience, if you just need to bind the service to get some data from the service, there is no need to do so.

Just use localbroadcastmanager. It is sufficient to send the data from the service to application. It is quite easy, safe, less prone to memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do need to expose some methods from the service. Thank you anyways.